# Spring Boot JpaRepository not importing

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Hello I am beginner and just started to learn spring boot and stuck on this. I am trying to create a CRUD application but JpaRepository is not working.

pom.xml (These are dependencies)

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Below is the service class image where it is not importing:
[Class Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDlJ8.png)

Comment: Simply way for us to check if dependency has been pulled in your local repo or not, is to do maven->update dependency (with force update) and then clean build your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have created class. That is not gonna work.

**Solution:-**

Create Interface and then extend JpaRepository like below:-(use meaningful name)

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

// add method if you have
}
```

Comment: Yeah! that was my bad thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You have to include `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency as well.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Problem has been solved

Comment: @Nadish: can you endorse for the answer so everyone knows this problem is solved.